# CSS placeing inline elements on top of each other in a in a div

Tags: html, css

I am developing the front end for one of my clubs in my school, and I am having problems placing two inline elements on top of each other. I have been stuck on this for a few nights and it is really upsetting me. I have tried everything from margin,positioning,inline-block, and all of it seems to give me one problem or the other. Right now I am at my wits end, so I am turning here. The  elements are suppose to be above the  elements. both elements are in the player  which is suppose to be next to the image. I will include the link to download my code, and where I am having the problem it pretty obvious once you see my page in a browser. Thanks for any help you can give me.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21141217/HvZ.zip

Edit: I am having an issue here

```
<div id="recentTags">
                <h4>RECENT TAGS</h4>
                <div class="tag">
                    <div class="player">
                        <a href="">Chris Stephenson</a>
                        <h6>Legends</h6>
                    </div>
                    <img src="tag.png" alt />
                    <div class="player">
                        <a href="">Eric Tadt</a>
                        <h6>butt pirates</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tag">
                    <div class="player">
                        <a href="">Zack Baer</a>
                        <h6>Little Bears</h6>
                    </div>
                    <img src="tag.png" alt />
                    <div class="player">
                        <a href="">Humble Trumble</a>
                        <h6>Glorious pres</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#recentTags{
width: 292px;
padding: 4px;
height: 236px;
/*My attempt at trying to recreate the color gradient. Gabe fix it*/
/*I used http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ or you can just google css gradient generator*/
background: #5e5e5e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5e5e5e 0%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5e5e5e), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5e5e5e 0%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5e5e5e 0%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5e5e5e 0%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5e5e5e 0%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5e5e5e', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#recentTags h4{
color: #D23000;
background-color: grey;
padding-left: 8px;
/*Color gradient*/
background: #2d2d2d;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #2d2d2d 0%, #4c4c4c 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#2d2d2d), color-stop(100%,#4c4c4c));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #2d2d2d 0%,#4c4c4c 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #2d2d2d 0%,#4c4c4c 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #2d2d2d 0%,#4c4c4c 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #2d2d2d 0%,#4c4c4c 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2d2d2d', endColorstr='#4c4c4c',GradientType=1 );
}
.tag{
width: 280px;
height: 31px;
margin-top: 5px;
padding:3px;
border: 0px solid #829485;
border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
/*Gradient*/
background: rgb(30,87,153);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(53,53,53,1) 2%, rgba(73,73,73,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(2%,rgba(53,53,53,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(73,73,73,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(53,53,53,1) 2%,rgba(73,73,73,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(53,53,53,1) 2%,rgba(73,73,73,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(53,53,53,1) 2%,rgba(73,73,73,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(53,53,53,1) 2%,rgba(73,73,73,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#494949',GradientType=0 );
}
.tag a{
color: #D23000;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
bottom: 14px;
}
.player{
width:110px;
display: inline;
}
.tag img{position: relative;}
.tag h6{
display: inline;
}
```

dabblet link: http://result.dabblet.com/gist/4007549/381ecd27edf3c72fbde28575ca9cd2e50e2c2a52

EDIT: I guess I choosed the wrong choice of words I want to place the  elements above the  elements. So the end result will look like this:

Chris Stephenson
  Legends

Comment: "The elements are supposed to be above the elements"? Which elements are meant to be above which other elements? Could you give the particular elements an obvious background-color, to make it easier to see where the problem is? Or at least identify them specifically with an `id` for example..?

Comment: All of the <a> elements are suppose to above the <h6> elements in each "player" div class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the player name to sit above the player team name, and both to sit to the left, with the image sitting to the right. The following answer assumes that this is correct. If it is not correct please specify what you mean with specifics.

To have an element followed by a line break, you want to style that element `display: block;`. 
`display: inline;` will make the elements sit side by side. 
So I think this is the first place you are going wrong. You want to make the player link and player team name `display: block;`.

Then float the player to the left and the image to the right.

Then clear the floats.

Then you end up with something like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NsfB4/

This is the css to do this:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.tag .player {
    float: left;
}
.tag .image { 
    float: right; 
}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="recentTags">
    <h4>RECENT TAGS</h4>
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="player">
            <a href="">Chris Stephenson</a>
            <h6>Legends</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="tag.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"><!-- --> </div>

        <div class="player">
            <a href="">Eric Tadt</a>
            <h6>butt pirates</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"><!-- --> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="player">
            <a href="">Zack Baer</a>
            <h6>Little Bears</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="tag.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"><!-- --> </div>

        <div class="player">
            <a href="">Humble Trumble</a>
            <h6>Glorious pres</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"><!-- --> </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Is this what you after (other than your gradient styling).